# For new test cases, how to stop the Tester field automatically defaulting to the name of whoever created the card?

Tags: azure

On creating a new test case in Azure Dev Ops, we've noticed the 'Tester' field is automatically set to the name of whoever created the card. This is incorrect, as testing on the card has not started and none of the QA team has picked it up yet. I imagine very few software companies have just one tester and instead have multiple people working through test suites once testing begins. How can this be changed to show that no testers have yet been assigned and the test case is waiting to be picked up by one of the team?

Comment: You'll need to edit the field in the test case template, to remove the Rule. There will be a rule on the 'Tester' field which auto-picks the assignee.

Comment: There doesn't appear to be any assigned rules at present. And there is nowhere to edit the 'Tester' field. Even if you create a new template, when you try to edit that template the 'Tester' field still doesn't show up.

Comment: So in the 'classic' TFS on-premise, you have a 'process template' which defines the fields as they appear in Visual Studio and the web view, and you can adjust the layout, set rules etc... in Azure Devops I don't know what the equivalent is, but 'Template' refers to a pre-filled in form for certain work item types. You'll need to dig around for the WIT (work item type) editor for Azure Devops. Your question might be better placed over on stack overflow.

Comment: I've found the process template for test cases, however the 'Tester' field doesn't appear as one of the areas that can be changed. It seems to be fixed. I've copied this question over at SO, so hopefully someone will have an answer. I imagine other test teams will have had the same issue.

Comment: Sorry I couldn't be more help. We use TFS on-premise here, so I'm not familiar with editing WIT for Azure Devops. Good luck agent! P.S. You'll probably find other baked-in rules such as a bug being assigned to the person who raised it, once it's set to Resolved.

Comment: No worries. Thanks for having a go! : )